# Is it possible to rotate shadow map in Three.js?

Tags: three.js, shadow

I have plane ground rectangle rotated by 90 degrees. And I have DirectionalLight which cast shadow on this plane. Look at this simple code example:

```
var Three = new function () {
    var scene = new THREE.Scene()

    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000)
    camera.position.set(-380, 252, 420);
    camera.rotation.order = 'YXZ';
    camera.rotation.y = -Math.PI / 4;
    camera.rotation.x = Math.atan(-1 / Math.sqrt(2));

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true

    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1)
    light.position.set(150, 100, 100)
    light.castShadow = true
    light.shadowDarkness = 0.3
    light.shadowCameraVisible = true
    light.shadowCameraRight = 50;
    light.shadowCameraLeft = -50;
    light.shadowCameraTop = 50;
    light.shadowCameraBottom = -50;
    scene.add(light);

    var ground = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(436, 624),
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: '#808080'})
    );
    ground.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
    ground.receiveShadow = true

    scene.add(ground);

    this.init = function () {
        $('body').append(renderer.domElement);
        Three.render();
    }
    this.render = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame(Three.render);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    Three.init();
});
```

Ground mesh is rotated by 90 degree. Can I rotate light shadow map? I would like to match it to the rotation of the ground?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/95t964o0/33/

Comment: Add a link to a jsfiddle so we can see it.

Comment: I don't know haw to add Three.js to jsfiddle

Comment: Here is a fiddle you can modify: http://jsfiddle.net/95t964o0/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/95t964o0/33/

Comment: what object casts a shadow?

Comment: so then how do you expect to see a shadow. there must be an object that casts one.

Comment: @gaitat this example is not about showing shadows. Question was about rotating shadow map (I'm not sure that I'm using correct name). In this example, there are lines from light source (I call area between those lines a shadow map). I want this lines to cross plane mesh corners.

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/87w27/

Comment: @gaitat No. In this fiddle direction of shadow is changing but shadow map does not rotate.

Comment: sorry I really don't understand your terminology.

Comment: What you want to do is cover all the ground mesh with the light frustum (I think that is called), right?

Comment: @arnaldex Yes, I think that this is what I want to do. Because if not all the ground mesh is covered then this part which is not covered don't get shadows. And I think that performance depends on the size of the area covered. So it would be preferred to cover exactly whole ground and not less or not more.